# How to create a session manually with WSO2 API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking for guidance on how to create a session manually using the WSO2 API. Specifically, I am working with WSO2 IS product. I've reviewed the documentation, but I couldn't find clear instructions or examples for manually creating a session.

I have checked https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/session-mgt-rest-api/

If this is not achievable, could someone please provide guidance on creating a custom endpoint for this specific purpose?

Additional Information:

- WSO2 IS version 6.0.0